# should we share on controller in two pages or should have different controller for different pages?

Tags: angularjs

I am making an application in angular Js, i am confused on making controllers. my question is, should we make one controller for one entity as we do in all server side MVC projects or we should have different controllers for different pages.

for example we have an Entity **User**

should we make a controller for user (**userCtrl**) and include that controller in all the pages for example create user, search user and delete user pages , the second option is to create different controller for different pages like createUserCtrl, searchUserCtrl etc?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally we should have controllers based on functionalities and not strictly on views.

Answer (score 2):

We should use different Controllers for different Views following best practices.

Comment: can you share some example or links?

Answer (score 0):

You actually would want to some type of `provider` to store a common object like an Entity User.

This can then be extended to be used in different `controllers` throughout the application.

[AngularJS Providers Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

[Also here is an example that uses two different controllers on the same view extending a provider that shares data between them.](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/JTWQ9/)

Basic `Factory` provider example.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController',['contacts',function(contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;

}])
.factory('contacts',function() {
   return [
      {
        "_id": "540f0d1c29d786a159f9a27e",
        "name": {
          "first": "Francis",
          "last": "Strong"
        },
        "company": "ZILLAN",
        "email": "francis.strong@zillan.com",
        "phone": "+1 (921) 507-2998"
      },
      {
        "_id": "540f0d1cf078b6b0cf3ac56f",
        "name": {
          "first": "Johanna",
          "last": "Rosario"
        },
        "company": "GLASSTEP",
        "email": "johanna.rosario@glasstep.ca",
        "phone": "+1 (958) 425-3942"
      }]; 
});
```

Comment: my question was is their is a way to add some thing in route to tell we want to execute this function of some controller on page load